# Old SQL? multiple tables after FROM

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to rewrite the following query which was generated in some part by Impromptu. For some reason I cannot get my head around the multiple tables after the FROM and the nest of joins that follows. I have always used a "master" table then joined anything I would need after that. i.e select from, left join (table) on x=x left join (table) on x=x and so on.

I'm having a difficult time with the parenths etc... in this. What would it look like written in "normal" query style? Thanks so much in advance!

```
select 
    T6."dateofservice"
    , getdate(), -20000 - (1 - convert(float(53),-2) / abs(-2)) / 2
    , T1."pgrp_specialty"
    , T1."pgrp_prov_combo"
    , T2."patsex"
    , T3."restricted"
    , T2."patdob"
    , T2."patdecdate"
    , T2."acctno"
    , T2."patno"
from 
    "acctdemo_t" T3, "transaction_t" T5,
    ("patdemo_t" T2 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ("provcode_t" T8 
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN "provalt_t" T1 on T8."px" = T1."accesspractice" and T8."provcode" = T1."accessprovidercode") on T2."provcode" = T8."provcode") 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "insset_t" T4 on T2."acctno" = T4."acctno" and T2."patno" =    T4."patno", "charge_t" T6 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN "poscode_t" T7 on T6."poscode" = T7."poscode"

where 
    T2."patsex" <> 'U' 
    and T7."posid" = '3' 
    and T6."correction" = 'N' 
    and T5."txtype" = 'C' 
    and (T4."defaultset" = 'Y' or 
           (T4."inssetno" = 0 or T4."inssetno" is null) 
         and T4."defaultset" is null) 
    and T6."chgno" = T5."chgno" 
    and T2."patno" = T6."patno" 
    and T2."acctno" = T6."acctno" 
    and T2."acctno" = T3."acctno"
```

Comment: FYI - this is how most old school DBAs learned to write SQL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL written with multiple tables, separated by comma is implied `INNER JOIN`, with the where clause serving as the join clause. For example,

```
select * from table1 a, table2 b
where a.id = b.id
```

is the same as:

```
select * from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

So, in your case, this part:

```
from "acctdemo_t" T3
, "transaction_t" T5
```

is implying inner join between `acctdemo_t` and `transaction_t`.

And - the third part of this:

```
("patdemo_t" T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ("provcode_t" T8 LEFT OUTER JOIN "provalt_t" T1 on T8."px" = T1."accesspractice" and T8."provcode" = T1."accessprovidercode") 
        on T2."provcode" = T8."provcode")
```

Is actually a tableset being created on the fly with its own clauses, and is basically acting as a table in this join. Also being joined with Inner join, since its added with a comma.

I believe this can definitely written to be more readable, and the inline tableset being created isn't going to be good for performance, but that totally depends on the number of records you have.

Comment: Thank you! with that clarification I should be able to re-write this more efficiently!